# change the color of a line between 2 points on a google map on an event

Tags: maps

I have a web page in which I am using google maps to show a particular Area on which I have boundaried it by drawing lines at various points(these points are the sensor we have placed)by providing its latitude and longitute . now I want to change the color of a specific line between 2 points. i.e. basically we are trying to identify suppose it at 1 boundary if there is anything that is unusual a signal will come . we need to read the signal and then on the map change the color of the specific line between the 2 points. how can I implement that. Any pointer will be of great help.
Thanks 
RVD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a line in any colour you like with google.maps.Polyline.